# setLayout(null) JTextField size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, null-layout-manager

I'm currently working on a small project that requires "null" layout of my `JPanel`.

When adding or editing a `JTextField`, is there any other way for me to have it visible without having to `setBounds()`?
What I want is for the height and width to be determined by the text size, and for me to set only the location of the text in my `JPanel`.

Comment: *"is there any other way for me to have it visible without having to setBounds()"* - No - that's what layout managers do. If you "must" deal without layout managers, then **you must** replace it's functionality.  I can't begin to tell you what a really  (I'm restraining my language at this point) decision it is to NOT use layout managers - this will be your single greatest work load

Comment: *"I'm currently working on a small project that requires "null" layout of my `JPanel`."* .. ***Why?***

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it to the default layout, do `setLayout(new BorderLayout());`

Comment: Requires a null layout

Comment: @Freebmdplz Then YOU must replace the functionality that the layout managers performed - this will become your single greatest workload